# Flutter: ElevatedButton with gradient background

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-layout

With the deprecated `RaisedButton` class, it was easy to create a gradient background for a button using the `decoration` property, and using the different Gradient classes with an array of Colors.

However, using the new and improved (?) `ElevatedButton` class, I just cant figure out how to accomplish this.
Every bit of online information refers to the deprecated use cases, and digging through the API docs I cant find something equivalent to `decoration`.

So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a `Container` with a `GestureDetector`

The `GestureDetector` will give you to `onTap` functionality.
The `Container` will provide the `decoration`

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
         // Decorate here
        ),
        child: Center(
          // Enter content here
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Apparently, the new ElevatedButton and OutlinedButton widgets do not support custom graphics and animation, so the only option is to do it 'vanilla' as described above. thanks for your answer.